# Bubble smartdiagram with borders?

Tags: smartdiagram

I was wondering whether there's any way to have smartdiagram do bubbles with borders, e.g. black borders around both planet and satellites. Here's the code I've used trying, though to no avail. Any help much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{border color = black,
    uniform color list=blue!30 for 8 items, 
    bubble center node color = blue!50,
    bubble center node size=5cm,
    bubble node size=3cm
}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{A,
    B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{border color = black,
    uniform color list=blue!30 for 8 items, 
    bubble center node color = blue!50,
    bubble center node size=5cm,
    bubble node size=3cm
}

\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={draw=black}}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{A,
    B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Works fine! Thanks a lot! In case anyone is interested how to get a b/w bubble diagram of the type I was querying about, here comes the code for that:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{border color = black,
    uniform color list=blue!30 for 8 items, 
    bubble center node color = none,
    bubble fill opacity=0,
    bubble center node size=5cm,
    bubble node size=3cm
}

\tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={draw=black, thin},
    bubble node/.append style={
        draw=black, thin}
}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{A,
    B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it looks:]